# saving changes to db

Tags: c#, datagridview

My database is not getting updated when I delete a row from my `DataGridView`.
Suppose I press the `Delete` key to delete a selected row on the `DataGridView` and then I make some other changes to other rows.

Finally I would press the `Save` button to save all these changes

Here's my code:

```
    private bool SaveData(DataGridView dgv)
        {
            bool bDone = true;
            DataTable dtVesselDataChanges;
            SQLiteCommand DeleteCmd = new SQLiteCommand();
            string sdeleteVesselCase = "  public string SQL_DeleteVesselDataCase = "delete from vesseldata where plantid = @plantid and fileid=@fileid and vdid=@vdid";"
            DeleteCmd.CommandText = sdeleteVesselCase;
 dtVesselDataChanges = gdt.GetChanges();

            if (dtVesselDataChanges.Rows.Count > 0 && dtVesselDataChanges != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dtVesselDataChanges.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (dtVesselDataChanges.Rows[i].RowState == DataRowState.Deleted)
                    {
                        int rowindexPlant = Convert.ToInt32(gdt.Rows[i]["PlantId", DataRowVersion.Original]);
                        int rowindexFile = Convert.ToInt32(gdt.Rows[i]["FileId", DataRowVersion.Original]);
                        int rowindexVDID = Convert.ToInt32(gdt.Rows[i]["VDID", DataRowVersion.Original]);
                        DeleteCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@plantid", rowindexPlant);
                        DeleteCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileid", rowindexFile);
                        DeleteCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VDID", rowindexVDID);
                        _DatabaseConnection.ExecuteQuery(DeleteCmd); ;

                    }
                }
            }
There is no error except DB is not updated
```

Comment: Is this function even called? I think there is no other way than to debug and see how it goes withing the function.

Comment: The code you have posted does not even compile. See the line `string sdeleteVesselCase = "  public string SQL_DeleteVesselDataCase = ...`.

Comment: @ Thorsten Dittmar: Sorry, I didnt think u will try to compile the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have correct delete command

```
DeleteCmd.CommandText = "delete from vesseldata where plantid = @plantid and fileid= @fileid and vdid=@vdid";
```

set parameters with same name in command Text.

```
DeleteCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@plantid", rowindexPlant);
DeleteCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileid", rowindexFile);
DeleteCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vdid", rowindexVDID);
```

Open `_DatabaseConnection` before `ExecuteQuery` if it is not already opened.

You will not get any errors if your application not come to `ExecuteQuery` line, debug and check whether your application come to that point and what is the command text, connection state and any errors.